# Pattern to force events to fire serially with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I'm making a bunch of ajax calls from the browser to a service and I'd like to be nice to the server by not sending them all at once. Is there a standard pattern for serializing the firing of a list of events so that the next one doesn't fire until the last one finished?

Comment: You could nest the calls inside the success callbacks of the previously called ajax calls.  That would be really ugly, though.  I'd like to see a better solution.

Comment: You could store a global list of ajax parameters, then have a function that processes them one by one. Bonus of that is, the result handler of the functions could actually queue additional requests

Comment: You could make the AJAX calls synchronous, but I expect you don't want to do that. Seems you need an AJAX queue manager, you could write your own or use an existing one. [Google](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=javascript+AJAX+queue+manager&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&client=firefox-a) turned up [AJAX Queue/Cache/Abort/Block Manager](http://webscripts.softpedia.com/script/AJAX/AJAX-Queue-Cache-Abort-Block-Manager-60972.html), there are sure to be others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [jQuery.whenSync() Plugin For Chaining Asynchronous Callbacks Using Deferred Objects](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2326-jQuery-whenSync-Plugin-For-Chaining-Asynchronous-Callbacks-Using-Deferred-Objects.htm) can help you queue AJAX calls.

Answer (score 0):

I do this now with one of my apps.  Basically I have an array that stores all my ajax call parameters.  On the callback I pass the next increment until there are no more.  Here's a general example (you could use ajax or get of course, this is just how I do it:

```
var params = [
{url : 'someurl', data : 'somedata', callback : doSomething},
{url : 'anotherurl', data : 'moredata'}
],
process = function(i) {

    if (i < params.length) {  

        var item = params[i];     

        // Navigate to first view trainee screen
        $.post(
            item.url,
            item.data,
            function(data) {
                // Could test for function, etc but this is how I do it
                try {
                     item.callback(data);
                } catch (e) {}

                process(++i);
            }
         );

    }
};


process(0);
```